# Syntax error on powershell and c++ INTEROP

Tags: c++

```
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <LM.h>
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")


#include <cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include <io.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/stat.h>   
#include <string>
#using <System.Management.Automation.dll>
void nick() {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Management::Automation;

    std::system("start powershell.exe -noexit -Command {Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force} -Command {.\zipdownload.ps1}");
                                                                                                               ^^ ERROR HERE ^^
}


int main() 
{

    nick();

}
```

I've managed to run the code below and compile with no errors but there's a syntax error when attempting to pass thru another -command, any ideas? running this, powershell outputs syntax error "unexpected { token" or whatnot.

Comment: That seems to be a PowerShell Question, not C++.
If I were to guess, I'd say your PS call should look like this: `start powershell.exe -noexit -command {Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force .\zipdownload.ps1}`

Comment: still nothing, even after i edited gpo policy to allow all ps scripts, on the verge of giving up ugh.